# Setting auto_flushing=1 in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, production

We have two production environments for our application. One is called "production". Other is called "UK". We are seeing memory leak in UK environment and we need to restart the servers every week because of this. One thing we found is that the auto_flushing is set 1 for uk environment whereas it is set to 1000 for production. The documentation says flushing less often will increase memory usage. Is there any chance that flushing more often will result in memory issues?

Answer (score 1):

No auto_flushing actually use less memory, but more IO load (can be slower potentially).

But I guess in Rails 3.1 this was deprecated and this setting is ignored.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c9cd0eb2d01c262b987070d739cf1d5e46672c10/activesupport/lib/active_support/buffered_logger.rb#L107